# Rasp Pi PPTPD Service Not Starting on Boot

Tags: boot, linux, vpn

I have configured the PPTPD serice on my Pi and it works well.

When I reboot the Pi the PPTPD service is not starting automatically.

When seaching Google there are many ways suggested.

Should I use something like `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` or upstart?

Please can someone advise which is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start a service automatically you probably want to use the `rc` framework.

In `/etc/` you will find a number of directories named

```
/etc/rc0.d
/etc/rc1.d
/etc/rc2.d
/etc/rc3.d
/etc/rc4.d
/etc/rc5.d
/etc/rc6.d
```

These represent [*runlevels*](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/runlevels.htm), and are filled with carefully named soft links to scripts in in `/etc/init.d/` directory that are executed in order in different stages of the startup and shutdown processes. The `/etc/init.d` directory is filled with scripts starting and stopping different services, and one of the scripts you will find there is the `pptpd` service script.

When you execute a command like `service pptpd start`, the `pptpd` script in `/etc/init.d` is executed with the `start` argument.

What you want to do is to start the pptpd service at runlevel 2. That means you create a soft link in the `/etc/rc2.d`-directory named `S16pptpd` that points to the `/etc/init.d/pptpd` script, like so:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/pptpd /etc/rc2.d/S16pptpd
```

- "S" is for "start"
- "16" is the ordering
- "pptpd" is a mnemonic

This will make sure that when your system enters runlevel 2, the pptpd service will be started.

Comment: Hi. Your answer was automatically "flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." Could you improve it to point out what to do and how it works?

Comment: Thanks, I can see why that would be. Expanded and elaborated the answer slightly.